# Open all files matching regex - python

Tags: python

I want to open and manipulate all files in a directory that have a numbered extension (eg. .342) My regex is '(.[0-9]{3})' I'm going to combine them all in one single file and massage them before outputting the new file.

I can't figure out what I'm supposed to feed the regex as input. I know I want to feed it the list of dir files. I guess I iterate through every file in the directory first, and put only the matched ones in matchlist, THEN I loop through matchlist and open them.

(I've looked at a bunch of examples.)

This is where I am so far.

```
import glob, os, re

Path = "data"
os.chdir(Path)

matchlist = re.search('(.[0-9]{3})', file )

for file in glob.glob(matchlist):
    with open(file) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) use a different syntax than regex.

You probably want either:

```
for filename in os.listdir():
    if re.search(r'(\.[0-9]{3})', filename): 
        # ...
```

or:

```
for file in glob.glob('./*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]'): 
    # ...
```

Comment: Yes. That was one stumbling block I was aware of. But your first example shows how I select only the files I want from the directory. Thanks.